# How to implament retractable screen in android

Tags: android

Recently I came across an app that implements a portion of screen that can be retracted.[image]

[image]

I have inserted two screenshots above.
Any help on how to implement this functionality is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library: https://github.com/Startappz/DobSliding

Or this one: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel